# Pass id to materialize modal laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, materialize

I'm trying to send the ID of a registered user to a modal for been able to edit the DB directly from the modal, but since it's a modal and not other page I can't use a routing method. And i don't know if it's possible using JavaScript

Here is my view code:

```
table class="highlight responsive-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" hidden>ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Nombre</th>
            <th data-field="last_name">Apellidos</th>
            <th data-field="course">Curso</th>
            {{-- <th data-field="date">Fecha</th> --}}
            <th style="text-align: right;">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        @foreach($professors as $professor)
            <tr>
                <td hidden>{{$professor->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$professor->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$professor->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$professor->course}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; width: 20em">

                    <button data-target="modalEdit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn yellow darken-2"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin:0">create</i></button>

                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modalEdit" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <form class="col s12" method="POST" action="/professors">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Editar a {{ $professor->name }}</h4>
            {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate" required>
                    <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="last_name"  name="last_name" type="text" class="validate" required>
                <label for="last_name">Apellidos</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="course" name="course" type="text" class="validate" required>
                <label for="course">Nombre de curso</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="file-field input-field">
            <div class="btn btn yellow darken-2">
                <span>Subir foto</span>
                <input type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Nota: Porás actualizar la foto usando el botón editar.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-2 ">Registrar</button>
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Cerrar</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
        $('#modalEdit').modal();
    });
</script>
```

I Need to pass the ID to the modal to get the info of the user from the DB.

Comment: Do you intend to open the `modal` on `clicking` the `button` with the class `darken-2`?

Comment: Exactly, the modal actually opens, since I do not pass any data the modal it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `id` by placing an attribute on your `DOM` button

```
<button data-target="modalEdit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn   yellow darken-2" data_professor_id="{{$professor->id}}"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin:0">create</i></button>
```

And place a `input[type="hidden"]` input inside the modal:

```
<div id="modalEdit" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
<form class="col s12" method="POST" action="/professors">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Editar a {{ $professor->name }}</h4>
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Hidden Input Professor Id -->
        <input type="hidden" name="professor_id" />
        ....
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then on clicking the button, you can use `attr` method to get that specific professor id and pass it in your new hidden `input` in your `modal`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.darken-2').click(function(event) {
        var sProfessorId = $(this).attr('data_professor_id');
        var oModalEdit = $('#modalEdit');
        oModalEdit.find('input[name="professor_id"]').val(sProfessorId);
        oModalEdit.modal();
    });

});
```

Hope this helps for your case

**Edit:** If you want to get the `{{ $professor->name }}` as well, apply the same method the same as you are passing the `id` as well.

```
// Add this in the button as well
data_professor_name="{{$professor->name}}"

$('button.darken-2').click(function(event) {
    var sProfessorId = $(this).attr('data_professor_id');
    var sProfessorName = $(this).attr('data_professor_name'); 
    var oModalEdit = $('#modalEdit');
    oModalEdit.find('input[name="professor_id"]').val(sProfessorId);
    oModalEdit.find('h4').html('Editar a ' + sProfessorName);
    oModalEdit.modal();
});
```

Comment: It's not working, `{{$professor->name}}` returns the last entry and not the ID sent

Comment: Because you place `{{$professor->name}}` when you load the page initially, thus you are getting its last entry. If you also want to get the `{{$professor->name}}` dynamically, you can also pass it like the `{{$professor->id}}`

Comment: I have change that, I use `{{$professor->name}}` for get the names from the DB dynamically, and also if I use `{{professor->id}}` it also returns the last entry, ignoring the data passed to the modal.

Comment: Did you've `inspect` the element `darken-2` in your `browser` you are using? Are you sure each of those `darken-2` DOM elements have dynamic values?

Comment: Yes, the `data_professor_id` has the correct ID from every registered professor and also the resulting value assigned in the script it's correct. but how this helps me to use `{{$professors->name}}` if only it's passing the value to the hidden input?

Comment: That workid, I can now complete all the inputs in my modal, thanks :D

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Kindly upvote the answer if this answer helps you